# Piping nc to sed and evaluate datetime for each row

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, text, nc

Could someone provide any idea, how could i pipe data from nc to sed (or awk, or anything) and evaluate and write to file a timestamp after each row?
What i have:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/ncserver.service
[Unit]
Description=netcat listener
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313 >> /opt/data/$(hostname)-$(date -u +%%y%%m%%d-%%H).txt'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

simple listener - receives text via raw tcp, sends into the file (restarts by cron once a day to generate new file)

I want to append current timestamp to each row of text coming (at the beginning or the end of the row, doesnt matter).
Tried sed, awk, but the problem is that i cannot evaluate `date` for each row - it evaluates only once, when service started.
Looks like this

```
109582 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313 | /usr/bin/sed 's/^/'$(date +%s)
 109583 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313
 109584 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/sed s/^/1617555467\;/g
```

Pipe may be not the answer at all, but i'm kinda limited by bash.
Any ideas?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` does not have the ability to run a command again and again each time you run a script (well, GNU `sed` has the `/e` flag which does this, but it's not generally portable) so you should probably switch to a tool which does this.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313 | awk "{ system(\"date +%s | tr \\047\\\\n\\047 \\047\\\\t\\047\") }1"
 >> /opt/data/$(hostname)-$(date -u +%%y%%m%%d-%%H).txt'
```

The quoting there is unsavory enough that you might want to save the command line in a separate script, and just put the path to that as the argument to `ExecStart`.  For example, if you saved this in `/usr/local/bin/dump1313`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313 |
awk '{ system("date +%s | tr \047\\n\047 \047\\t\047") }1' >> /opt/data/$(hostname)-$(date -u +%%y%%m%%d-%%H).txt
```

and `chmod a+x` this file, you can then simply put

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dump1313
```

(There are no Bash-specific commands here, so I put `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/usr/bin/bash` or what have you.)

Running `tr` to get rid of the line terminator from `date` is still rather a wart. If you want to make this self-contained and resource-efficient, perhaps create a simple C wrapper which adds a time stamp to each line it reads and prints ... or Python if C is too challenging:

```python
import sys
from datetime import datetime

for line in sys.stdin:
    print('{0}\t{1}'.format(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()), line), end='')
```

Comment: `root@cleanline-0001:~# cat /usr/local/bin/nclisten

#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/nc -n -v -l -k -p 1313 | /usr/bin/awk -W interactive '{ printf "%s",$0 ";" } {system("date -u +%s")}'  >> /opt/data/`hostname`-`/usr/bin/date -u +%y%m%d-%H`.txt`

for history, dunno, may be some poor soul will need this piece of... errr... "code" )))

Comment: Probably prefer modern `$(...)` command substitution syntax over obsolescent backtick syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to append current timestamp to each row of text coming (at the beginning or the end of the row, doesnt matter).

This sounds very like what [syslog](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) does. You might be able to replace `nc` with something like [pysyslog](https://pypi.org/project/pysyslog) and have it capture the text on the socket and append the date.